# ios how can implement a switchs/case with string?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, switch-statement

I want to implement a switchs/case where I can use a string to evaluate the switch case.

```
switch (tmp) {            
    case one: 
        NSLog(@"the string value of tmp is one");
        break;
```

any of you knows how can I implement something like this?

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can not use string in switch case statement, you can use only int or char data type.
But as i think your question is to make switch case more easy to understandable or readable.
So you can make enum for that, like:

```
typedef enum {
    zero,//by default the value starts from zero. 
    one,
    two
} NumCount;
```

> At the point you have use it.

```
NumCount tmp = one;

switch (tmp) {            
    case one: 
        NSLog(@"the string value of tmp is one");
        break;
}
```

> I think you understand what i want to say. If you have any doubt please ask from me.

Comment: I think the question is not correctly posted and that's why you posted this answer but you are not using strings, you are actually using integers in your `switch`

Comment: Yes my friend you are right, Please tell me what you want

Comment: :)), I'm not the one who posted it :))

Comment: oooh, i am so sorry.:)